# Why is my date output appearing weird?

Tags: jquery, sql, date

I'm using a jquery datepicker to get a date with a condition applied to it.

This is in my head file:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#delivery_date" ).datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        minDate : new Date(),
        onSelect: function(str) {

            var lastDate = new Date(),
            nums = str.split("-"),
            userDate = new Date(nums[2], nums[1]-1, nums[0]),
            period = 21;

            lastDate.setDate(lastDate.getDate()+period);

            if (userDate<lastDate) {
                $("#delivery_warning").addClass("show");
            }
            else { $("#delivery_warning").removeClass("show"); }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

And then on the page I have this to display the picker:

```
<input type="text" id="delivery_date" name="delivery_date" required />
<div id="delivery_warning">This date is within 3 weeks from today</div>
```

However when I select a date, it appears in the right format (eg 12-04-1987) but it goes into the database like '0000-00-00' for every date I select.

The SQL table field is set to date (and it must remain like this).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If it appears in the correct format then the problem is most likely server-side.  Can you post the scripts that pushes the data to the db?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I can, this is actually K2Store working on Joomla 3, so I'm not sure what file is used to push the data to the database. I think the problem could lie in that the input field is a text type, but the database field is a date type. (originally it was text but i had to change it to get another feature working)

Comment: Most likely you are posting date "dd-mm-yyyy" while sql expects standard date to be "yyyy-mm-dd"

Comment: Hmm maybe.. but if I change the format to yyyy-mm-dd then i get 20132013-11-12, whilst if i change to yy-mm-dd it shows as 2013-11-12 but then its in the wrong format, and the rule doesn't apply anyway above because the calculations are then wrong.

Comment: Change it to `yy-mm-dd` -- `yy` means 4-digit year.

Comment: Please read the rest of my comment.. I cant change it to yy because the ruling above won't work. Maybe i need to start again with the conditioning. basically, i want a div class to be added when the date selected is WITHIN RANGE from today upto 21 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL expects dates to be formatted like `1987-12-04`, not `12-04-1987`. So either change your datepicker to use:

```
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
```

or change your MySQL code to use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to parse the date in the format you're providing.

To get the selected date, don't use your `str.split()` code, use:

```
userDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
```

Here's how you can display the date in one format, but send it to the server in a different format. Add a hidden input field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="delivery_date" id="hidden_delivery_date">
```

and change the original `delivery_date` field to:

```
<input type="text" name="displayed_delivery_date" id="delivery_date">
```

Then add the following options to your datepicker:

```
altField: "hidden_delivery_date",
altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
```

and leave the `dateFormat:` option as you originally wrote it.

Comment: Just to confirm, are you talking yy-mm-dd? because the date i put is in dd-mm-yy

Comment: If you want the datepicker to format the date so that mysql's default date parser will understand it, you have to use yy-mm-dd. I recommend making the input field readonly, so that it can only be updated through the datepicker, not by typing directly.

Comment: Thank you. I'm ery much closer. :) The only thing now, is the date shown in the field is in yy-mm-dd but I can live with that.

Comment: You could use `altField` and `altFormat`. Point `altField` to a hidden input that's used for the database, and put that in `yy-mm-dd` format, while the displayed field uses `dd-mm-yy` format and is ignored by the server script.

Comment: Sorry, I wouldn't know exactly how to code that, would you mind giving an example?

Comment: I've added an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

As you see `0000-00-00` , MySQL need format to be  1987-12-04 instead of 12-04-1987.
Try to format your date correctly in client or server side.